# Iterate over slots (children) in svelte 3

Tags: svelte

I wanted to wrap all slots of my custom component. But I couldn't iterate over the slots. My custom component usage looks like:

```html
<Tab>
    <span slot="header">Tab Header 1</span>
    <span slot="header">Tab Header 2</span>
    <span slot="header">Tab Header 3</span>

    ... maybe other slots that are not "header"
</Tab>
```

Then inside `Tab.svelte`:

```
{#each ?? as slot}
    <a class="tab-item">
        <each-slot />
    </a>
{/each}
```

Above, I am trying to iterate over the children/slots named "header" and wrap them with an anchor tag. How can I do that?

**Edit**: I don't want to pass javascript objects like:

```html
<Tab headers={['Header 1', 'Header 2', 'Header 3']}>
```

Answer (score 17):

It's not possible to iterate over slots. An easier way to do what you describe is to use the [context API](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/context-api) to have the tabs and their panels work together.

[Here's an example of what I'm talking about](https://svelte.dev/repl/8e68120858e5322272dc9136c4bb79cc?version=3.5.1) — we should probably get round to tidying this up and making it available as an npm package, but hopefully it's a good enough base to build upon in its current state.

Comment: Context doesn't solve the general case and I've run into this as well. Sometimes the parent needs to be able to wrap each of an arbitrary list of elements. For instance I'm building a grid component that needs to wrap all its children in a cell element that applies some CSS to center the content within the cell.

Comment: What's the point of exporting the `TABS` object? Isn't a context available to all children? Why not simply use a string?

Comment: Using an object ensures that only components with a reference to `TABS` can get or set that context. If you used a string like `"TABS"` then any component could access it, potentially causing conflicts or mischief. It's unlikely, but using `{}` is promoted as a best practice for that reason

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it’s impossible. It’s a limitation of Svelte’s compile-time approach.

What you can do is create a wrapper component designed to be used in conjunction with `Tab`, e.g. `TabItem`. Then you’d have something like this:

TabItem.svelte:

```html
<a class="tab-item">
    <slot></slot>
</a>
```

Your example of a component that uses `Tab`:

```js
<Tab>
    <TabItem>
        <span slot="header">Tab Header 1</span>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <span slot="header">Tab Header 2</span>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <span slot="header">Tab Header 3</span>
    </TabItem>
</Tab>
```

It’s quite verbose when applied to your example. In practice, I’m guessing you’ll want to do something like this:

```html
<script>
    const items = [
        'Tab Header 1',
        'Tab Header 2',
        'Tab Header 3',
    ];
</script>

<Tab>
    {#each items as item (item)}
        <TabItem>
            <span slot="header">
        </TabItem>
    {/each}
</Tab>
```

in which case, wrapping the child in a loop is a manageable overhead.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
let slots = $$props.$$slots
```

Comment: You cant just drop any random code , please make your answers more clear and pacific